# How many ways are there to color a $3 × 3$ grid in the same way if five squares have to be red and four squares have to be blue?

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

When configurations after rotations and flips are considered the same, how many ways are there to color a $3 × 3$ grid in the same way if five squares have to be red and four squares have to be blue?
We can color a $3 × 3$ grid in $$\frac{n^9 + 4n^6 + n^5 + 2n^3}{8}$$ ways using $n$ colors if configurations after rotations and flips are considered the same.

But I couldn't find how many ways are there when the grid has five squares have to be red and four squares have to be blue. How can I calculate this?

Comment: So this is really the number of possible "final configurations" of a tic-tac-toe game, up to symmetry, if the game is played out even after someone gets 3-in-a-row.

Comment: Is this for a class?  The problem is small enough that you could just enumerate them by hand.

Comment: [coding challenge accepted](https://tinyurl.com/yzqdzgc5) Found 23 unique configurations

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating the symmetries of the grid for the cycle index so that we
may apply PET we obtain

- The identity, $a_1^9.$
- Two rotations by $90$ and $270$ degrees which fix
  the central slot, $2 a_1 a_4^2$
- One rotation by $180$ degrees which also fixes the central slot,
  $a_1 a_2^4$
- A vertical and a horizontal flip, which fixes the central column /
  row: $2 a_1^3 a_2^3$
- A flip about one of the two diagonals which are being fixed,
  $2 a_1^3 a_2^3.$

We get for the cycle index

$$Z(Q) = \frac{1}{8}
(a_1^9 + 2 a_1 a_4^2 + a_1 a_2^4 + 4 a_1^3 a_2^3).$$

Just to check we get for colorings using at most $N$ colors

$$\frac{1}{8} (N^9 + 4 N^6 + N^5 + 2 N^3)$$

which gives the sequence

$$1, 102, 2862, 34960, 252375, 1284066, 5105212, \ldots$$

which points to [OEIS A217331](https://oeis.org/A217331)
where these data are confirmed.

Now we use PET to compute the number of  colorings with five red 
squares and four blue ones, essentially performing

$$[R^5 B^4] Z(Q; R+B),$$

which yields (substitution is $a_d = R^d B^d$)

- $[R^5 B^4] (R+B)^9 = {9\choose 5} = 126$
- $[R^5 B^4] 2 (R+B) (R^4 + B^4)^2
  = 2 [R^4 B^4] (R^4 + B^4)^2  = 4$
- $[R^5 B^4] (R+B) (R^2 + B^2)^4
  = [R^4 B^4] (R^2 + B^2)^4
  = [R^2 B^2] (R + B)^4 \\ = {4\choose 2} = 6$
- $[R^5 B^4] 4 (R+B)^3 (R^2 + B^2)^3
  \\ = [R^5 B^4] 4 (R^3 + 3 R^2 B + 3 R B^2 + B^3)
  (R^2 + B^2)^3
  \\ = 4 ( {3\choose 1} + 0 + 3 {3\choose 2} + 0)
  = 48.$

We thus get for our answer $\frac{1}{8} (126 + 4 + 6 + 48)
= 23.$

Comment: Glad we arrived at the same results. I do not know what PET stands for but it seems efficient, could you point me to some link explaining this method ?

Comment: This is the [Polya Enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).